# Connection String for Globaly access

Tags: asp.net-mvc, connection-string

Where we can put

`Connection String(string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;) for Globaly access? in Asp.Net MVC`.

I want to put Connection String in a file and access for all the Classes. in Asp.Net MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static class to manage the access to the connection string:

```
using System.Configuration;

public static class Connection
{
    public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

Now you can access the connection string from anywhere in your application using `Connection.GetConnectionString()`.

How to use:
In your controllers, services, or other classes, you can access the connection string as needed: `string connectionString = Connection.GetConnectionString();`